# Ceating a VR Portal in quest passthrough not working in build for specific unity version (2022.3.9)

Tags: unity-game-engine, oculus, oculusquest, urp

I'm following this video tutorial (https://youtu.be/3iGrUy1Ah88?si=B_9ZcSWqp2ptozwr) to make a VR portal in mixed reality world. Its working fine when I use unity editor version 2020.3.5 but when I do the same with editor version 2022.3.9 its working in editor not in the build, in build its displaying the portal as grey plane & the inner world is displaying normally not inside the portal (which is like a vertical plane in the environment). Unity version 2020.3.5 uses URP 10 &  unity version 2022.3.9 uses URP 14. Do I need to make do any further set-up for URP 14.

[SS of the build took by unity editor version 2020.3.5 (URP 10)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbgEL.jpg) 
[SS of the build took by unity editor version 2022.3.9 (URP 14)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svNs3.png)

Do I need to set-up anything in my editor to support on build.

THANKS!!

Answer (score 0):

Finaly found the solution, in unity editor version 2020.3.5 the quality setting using forward renderer that is common for all type of quality setting. But in unity editor version 2022.3.9 that has different Renderer has 3 different types, so we have to set for all the quality settings.

Comment: "the quality setting using forward renderer that is common for all type of quality setting" I am confused.